# apex inputCheckbox required=TRUE not working

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes, apexinputfield, required

I have an  with required="TRUE".  For some reason it isn't getting throwing error even if I save it without checking the box.

Here's the VF Code.

```
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="margin-t3" layout="block" >
        <div class="row">           
            <div class="form-group no-margin">                                                                                                        
                 <apex:inputCheckbox required="TRUE" value="{!app.Reviewed__c}" id="Reviewed"/>
                 <label> I verify that I have reviewed this. </label>                                 
            </div>              
        </div><!--  end row -->
    </apex:outputPanel>


<apex:commandlink styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" action="{!navigator}" id="nextlink" onComplete="rerunjs();" reRender="webform" status="onsubmit">
    <apex:commandButton value="Save & Continue" id="continuebutton" />
</apex:commandlink>
```

In the class though, I just update app.  No errors and the page redirects to the next page.

I want to make the checkbox mandatory in the VF page itself.  I don't want to touch apex for this.  Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: Are you using `immediate="true"` somewhere on the command button for example?

Comment: Nope, im not using.  I will update the command button code also here.

Comment: On the other hand how do you want to make the checkbox mandatory? Should it be implicitly checked? If a checkbox is not checked it will get a value nevertheless (false). From my point of view it is not necessary to make a checkbox mandatory. It will get a value in any case. Checked -> TRUE, not checked -> FALSE.

Comment: This is like Read Terms & Conditions checkbox.  Must be checked by everyone.  I used Reruired="true"

Comment: You should do the check in controller.

Comment: What is the use of "required" attribute.  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I think it is a kind of "bug" or superfluous feature for the checkbox...

Comment: Can you add a Validation Rule to the Field on the Object?  That way it will always work regardless of this is a VF Page, Standard Detail Page, or API integration. It also requries 0 lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

The required attribute doesn't work in the checkbox the way you expect.  Since false (unchecked) is a valid answer, the form can submit.  What you need to do is add a validation in your save code that tests the checkbox and either saves or pushes a page message to the user about the requirement to check the box.